# как использовать Glide library для видео файлов(получить превью всех видео)

Tags: java, android

Имеется папка ан карте памяти, в которую сохраняется записанное видео в формате .mp4. 
В доках к либе нашел пример:

```
Display of Local Videos
```

Another step up from Gifs are videos. Glide is also able to display the thumbnail of videos, as long as they're stored on the phone. Let's assume you get the file path by letting the user select a video:

```
String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/example_video.mp4";

Glide  
    .with( context )
    .load( Uri.fromFile( new File( filePath ) ) )
    .into( imageViewGifAsBitmap );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Набросал класс:

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private String[] mDataset;
    ArrayList videoFiles = getVideoFiles(MainActivity.PATCH);

```
// класс view holder-а с помощью которого мы получаем ссылку на каждый элемент
// отдельного пункта списка
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // наш пункт состоит только из одного TextView
    public VideoView mVideoView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    }
}

// Конструктор
public RecyclerAdapter(String[] dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
}

// Создает новые views (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recysel_view, parent, false);
    // тут можно программно менять атрибуты лэйаута (size, margins, paddings и др.)

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Заменяет контент отдельного view (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.mVideoView.setVideoPath(mDataset[position]);//воспроизводим

}

// Возвращает размер данных (вызывается layout manager-ом)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}

public ArrayList<String> getVideoFiles(String directoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File files[] = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".MP4");
        }
    });

    for (File file : files) {
        result.add(file.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

а как теперь правильно использовать 
glide?

```
Glide  
.with(  )
.load( Uri.fromFile( new File(PATCH ) ) )
.into(  );
```

**R.layout.recysel_view**
Разметка:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Prefernce">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Item**

```
    <GridLayout android:id="@+id/fragmetn_galery_video"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:background="@color/theme_window_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >


    <VideoViewView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Я может чего не понимаю, но в переменной `filePath` Вы указываете путь до конкретного файла, а не папки.

Comment: @ post_zeew , может и я чего-то не понимаю,но зачем мне превью 1-го видео?если у меня их может быть 100 и больше...в доках про это не сказано...да и я указал, что у меня папка

Comment: @upward, согласно приведённому вами фрагменту доков либа сия может вам по пути к видео показать превбюшку оного в виде картинки. Проиграть видео она не может. Так же как и понять что вы хотите когда передаёте ей путь к папке с видео. Мы вот тоже ваш вопрос не поняли

Comment: Вы можете написать метод, который бы по пути к папке возвращал бы список путей до всех видео-файлов в этой папке, а далее каждый элемент полученного списка обработать с помощью `Glide`.

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб так я понял что там сказано,а если мне нужно отобразить именно видео?т.е не проигрывать,а хотя бы эскизов ..

Comment: У Вас есть путь к папке с видео-файлами, Вы хотите получить превью всех этих видео-файлов, верно?

Comment: @ post_zeew совершенно верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Постановка задачи:

Отобразить список превью видео-файлов (формата `mp4`), содержащихся в выбранной папке.

### Решение:

Для выбора папки с видео-файлами будем использовать [`Android-DirectoryChooser`](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser).

В `build.gradle` добавляем:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
}

...

dependencies {
...
    compile ('net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
}
```

В `AndroidManifest.xml` к тегу `manifest` добавляем атрибут:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

к тегу `application` добавляем:

```
tools:replace="android:theme"
```

Также не забываем про `permisson`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

*Так как целью данного ответа не стоит объяснение работы с `runtime permissions`, то здесь пользуемся старым способом, и, если `targetSdk >= 23`, то понижаем ее хотя бы до `22`.*

Далее, `layout` элемента списка `video_preview_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/video_preview_image_view"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/video_preview_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/video_preview_image_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`layout` для `activity` – `activity_preview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/video_preview_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choose_dir_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose dir"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Модель данных `VideoPreview`:

```
public class VideoPreview {
    private String mVideoName;
    private Bitmap mVideoBitmap;

    public VideoPreview(String videoName, Bitmap videoBitmap) {
        mVideoName = videoName;
        mVideoBitmap = videoBitmap;
    }

    public String getVideoName() {
        return mVideoName;
    }

    public Bitmap getVideoBitmap() {
        return mVideoBitmap;
    }
}
```

Адаптер для `RecyclerView`:

```
public class VideoPreviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoPreviewAdapter.VideoPreviewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<VideoPreview> mItems;

    public VideoPreviewAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItems(ArrayList<VideoPreview> items) {
        mItems.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearItems() {
        mItems.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public VideoPreviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.video_preview_item, parent, false);
        return new VideoPreviewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoPreviewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mVideoPreviewImageView.setImageBitmap(mItems.get(position).getVideoBitmap());
        holder.mVideoPreviewTextView.setText(mItems.get(position).getVideoName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public class VideoPreviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mVideoPreviewImageView;
        public TextView mVideoPreviewTextView;

        public VideoPreviewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mVideoPreviewImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_preview_image_view);
            mVideoPreviewTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_preview_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и, наконец, `PreviewActivity`:

```
public class PreviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DirectoryChooserFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private RecyclerView mVideoPreviewRecyclerView;
    private Button mChooseDirButton;

    private DirectoryChooserFragment mDialog;

    private VideoPreviewAdapter mVideoPreviewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preview);

        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.video_preview_recycler_view);
        mChooseDirButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_dir_button);
        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mVideoPreviewAdapter = new VideoPreviewAdapter(this);
        mVideoPreviewRecyclerView.setAdapter(mVideoPreviewAdapter);

        final DirectoryChooserConfig config = DirectoryChooserConfig.builder()
                .newDirectoryName("DialogSample")
                .build();
        mDialog = DirectoryChooserFragment.newInstance(config);

        mChooseDirButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectDirectory(@NonNull String path) {
        ArrayList<String> videoFiles = getVideoFiles(path);

        if (videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In this directory there is no videos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDialog.dismiss();
            return;
        }

        mDialog.dismiss();
        ArrayList<VideoPreview> videoPreviews = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String filePath : videoFiles) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            String videoFileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            videoPreviews.add(new VideoPreview(videoFileName, bitmap));
        }

        mVideoPreviewAdapter.clearItems();
        mVideoPreviewAdapter.addItems(videoPreviews);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelChooser() {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getVideoFiles(String directoryPath) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        File files[] = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".mp4");
            }
        });

        for (File file : files) {
            result.add(file.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Для получения превью используется метод `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(...)`, включенный в `Android SDK` (по этой причине не вижу смысла тащить `Glide`).

**Обратите внимание**, что метод `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(...)` весьма тяжеловат и при большом количестве файлов он будет вешать `UI`, поэтому лучше вынести его в отдельный поток и давать адаптеру по одному превью (по мере их формирования). Но это задачка уже для Вас.

**Также замечу, что в адаптере мы храним довольно объемный такой списочек**, размер которого обусловлен наличием массы `Bitmap` в нем. Подумайте: возможно нам это и не нужно. Но так как пример учебный, здесь оставим все как есть.

В итоге получаем следующее:

Диалог выбора папки с видео:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Список с превьюшками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: буду пробовать,благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Метод `getFiles(...)` по пути к папке возвращает список путей к ее файлам с определенным расширением:

```
public ArrayList<String> getVideoFiles(String directoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File files[] = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".mp4");
        }
    });

    for (File file : files) {
        result.add(file.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что видео-файлы могут иметь различные расширения, здесь реализовано только одно.

Пусть в `path` указан путь до папки с видео-файлами. Получаете список видео-файлов из этой папки:

```
ArrayList<String> videoFiles = getVideoFiles(path);
```

Далее с помощью `Glide` Вы можете необходимым образом обработать каждый видео-файл.

Так как количество видео-файлов в папке заранее неизвестно, то для вывода их первьюшек можно воспользоваться, например, `RecyclerView`, каждый элемент которого будет содержать `ImageView`.

Вы можете передать список `videoFiles` в адаптер `RecyclerView`'а и в нем, в методе `onBindViewHolder(...)` уже для каждого файла из `videoFiles` пользоваться соответствующим методом `Glide` для вывода превью очередного видео в соответствующий элемент списка `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47706/discussion-on-answer-by-post-zeew---glide-library---).